# Initialise complex object

Tags: c++, c++11, arduino, embedded

What options are available to create an object with lots of parameters in the global namespace? I'm thinking of the tradeoff between temporary object/variable creation and readability.

## Edit

This is for embedded programming on the Arduino. It will be the main object of a reusable library controlling a set of nested objects.


**Background:** I have a test PCB which can be populated differently depending on its final use and I need to cover all of these options in one easy to use library. I am trying to avoid the user accidently missing required initialisation parameters before using the object.

Feel free to constructively criticise my code!

The two options that I can think of are:

1. A constructor with lots of parameters.
2. A constructor with a single struct parameter.

Option 1 looks messy and hard to follow with lots of parameters.
Option 2 requires a temporary struct variable for readability.

Example below (normally I would separate into headers etc.):

```
#include <Arduino.h>
class NestedClass {
public:

  // Empty constructor for creation of unitialised object. Bad practice?
  NestedClass() {
  }

  // Main constructor.
  NestedClass(float voltageReference) :
      voltageReference_(voltageReference) { // Use initialisation list.
  }

  float measureVoltage(uint_fast8_t channel) {
    // Convert ADC value to absolute voltage.
    return analogRead(channel) * (voltageReference_ / 1023);
  }

private:
  float voltageReference_;
};

class ComplexClass {
public:

  enum class Mode
    : uint_fast8_t {
      MODE1,
    MODE2,
    MODE3
  };

  struct Parameters {
    uint_fast8_t parameter1;
    uint8_t parameter2;
    float parameter3;
    float parameter4;
    Mode mode;
    float voltageReference;
  };

  // Empty constructor for creation of unitialised object. Bad practice?
  ComplexClass(void) {
  }

  // Big constructor. Messy when used.
  ComplexClass(uint_fast8_t parameter1, uint8_t parameter2, float parameter3,
      float parameter4, Mode mode, float voltageReference) {
    // Could have used initialisation list instead.
    this->parameter1_ = parameter1;
    this->parameter2_ = parameter2;
    this->parameter3_ = parameter3;
    this->parameter4_ = parameter4;
    this->mode_ = mode;
    this->nestedClass_ = NestedClass(voltageReference); // Wasted temporary object with reassignment?
  }

  // Alternative constructor. Looks neater/more legible when used.
  ComplexClass(Parameters parameters) {
    this->parameter1_ = parameters.parameter1;
    this->parameter2_ = parameters.parameter2;
    this->parameter3_ = parameters.parameter3;
    this->parameter4_ = parameters.parameter4;
    this->mode_ = parameters.mode;
    this->nestedClass_ = NestedClass(parameters.voltageReference); // Wasted temporary object with reassignment?
  }

  void megaMeasurements() {
    // Do something involving nestedClass.measureVoltage().
  }

private:
  // Maybe put all of these in another struct for neatness?
  uint_fast8_t parameter1_;
  uint8_t parameter2_;
  float parameter3_;
  float parameter4_;
  Mode mode_;

  NestedClass nestedClass_;
};

//####################
// Start main code.
//####################

// Option 1:
// Not immediately obvious which value is for which parameter.
ComplexClass complexClass(1, 2, 3.30, 2.7, ComplexClass::Mode::MODE2, 5.00);

// Option 2:
// Unitialised object (sort-of).
ComplexClass complexClass2;

// Arduino standard function. Called once from main.cpp
void setup() {
  // Option 2 continued:
  ComplexClass::Parameters parameters;
  parameters.mode = ComplexClass::Mode::MODE2;
  parameters.parameter1 = 1;
  parameters.parameter2 = 2;
  parameters.parameter3 = 3.30;
  parameters.parameter4 = 2.7;
  parameters.voltageReference = 5.00;
  complexClass2 = ComplexClass(parameters); // Reassignment. Wasteful?
}

// Arduino standard function. Called in a continuous loop after setup().
void loop() {
  complexClass.megaMeasurements();
  complexClass2.megaMeasurements();
}
```

Comment: voted to close as opinion-based (you don't define "best").

Comment: Instead of passing a lot of individual parameters, maybe group them into logical structures, i.e. other objects, and pass a few of them? And maybe you should rethink your design, does the object *really* need all those parameters? Can't some of them have default values? And you can of course overload the constructor so you have one which uses a certain set of arguments, and another constructor that uses some other arguments.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf Reworded to "What options are available"

Comment: Put the initialization code inside a lambda that returns the full object and invoke the lambda in-place.

Comment: Personally I'd use a struct or an object. Or better, as @JoachimPileborg said, a set of different constructors (some with few parameters and default ones, some with more parameters). I'd avoid passing too many params to a function because the compiler will need to reserve some memory every call

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Thanks for the ideas. The ComplexClass with be the main entry point for a reusable library that controls a test PCB that can be populated deifferently depending on its final use. The parameters specify, amongnst other things, which hardware is fitted/usable. I wanted to make the libray as fool proof as possible so that future users are less likely to miss required parameters.

Comment: @ildjarn I've not used lambdas before. I'll look into this. Thanks

Comment: @frarugi87 Thanks. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

My opinion (based on my practice):

- constructor with many parameters look messy and should better be avoided. More, if some parameters are bad, you can't return "false" and the only way to complain is to throw an exception. If you want to go this way, it's better to define some init() function with several parameters, optionally returning false (or some error code) to complain if parameters are bad. In this case it's better to avoid literal numeric values using #define or static const declarations.
- The other way is to assign values one by one, either directly (public) or with set() methods. In this case you can put literals in the code.

Comment: Good point about the bad values. I am trying to reduce the potential for a user missing a required parameter as much as possible.